# firefox specific css padding

Tags: html, css

This css rule works fine in IE and chrome.

In Firefox it requires padding-bottom to be 8px.
I have tried several methods but nothing seems to work.

```
.wish 
{ 
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: -7px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

I tried this

```
.wish, x:-moz-any-link, x:default 
{
    padding-bottom:8px;
}
```

but firefox is ignoring it.

Comment: There's almost positively a css only way to write this universally. if if firefox is the browser rendering differently - as in, it's actually NOT IE giving you a problem - then there is most likely a more optimized way to write it out

Comment: @KaiQing since IE9 was released I've been stumped far more often on Firefox layout bugs than IE. I've even encountered a case where I thought IE did something wrong, then after reading specs scrutinously had to reluctantly decide that it was probably following standards better than Gecko and Webkit. I do agree however that this is highly unlikely to be a Firefox bug.

Comment: @niels - It was hard for me to choke down that IE9 actually did render well and had better performance with many heavy css animations via js than firefox and even chrome. Unfortunately, their reasonable success with 9 doesn't mask the fact that 8 and 7 are still gigantic pieces of sh** - nevermind 6 or below. That's pretty much the only reason I group all IE complaints together.

Comment: @KaiQing Firefox 0.1 (back then still called Phoenix) was originally released in 2002, a year after IE6, and is a crap browser by today's standards. Firefox 1.5, released around the time IE7 was released, is a piece of shit by today's standards. Firefox 3.0, released around the time IE8 was released, is total crap by today's standards. And IE8 was actually already pretty good in its time. Just saying - can't judge a program by its performance 12 years later. IE6 was even a pretty damn good browser in 2001, just a shame that so many people kept using for 10 years.

Comment: @niels - yeah but firefox had the decency to auto update. IE gets such a bad rep cause every PC based business alive requires tech people to update their PCs and as a result, never update IE till the machines are replaced. I thought IE9 introduced auto updating, but I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @KaiQing IE10 has automatic updates enabled by default ([proof](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/images/tech/748-ie10-updates.png)), and IE updates have been actively pushed via Windows Update since IE8. Companies sometimes do have valid reasons not to be able to upgrade, far more often because of incapable web developers than anything else. Also don't forget that Firefox broke its automatic updates in the 3 branch, and many people worldwide unaware of that are still stuck on 3.5 or 3.6 today.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it I put `.wish, x:-moz-any-link, x:default {
padding-bottom:8px;
}` below the orignal .wish rule and it works.

before I was declaring it on the top

Comment: I somehow can't help but think this is an [XY-solution to your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/219504).

Comment: I have fixed it I just have to declared it at the bottom. Thank you

Comment: No you have implemented a solution. I just can't help but think it's the right solution to the wrong problem, and the real issue is still there, causing layout problems like this. Firefox doesn't just introduce paddings out of nowhere without a reason.

Comment: yes I am surprised as well, like firefox hardly had given me any trouble before. Might be something wrong with my other css rules.